# Place text and a hyperlink inside an <input>

Tags: html

I'm trying to do something i think should be simple but i'm not getting it right, these are the lines i have written with no luck:

```
<input type="checkbox"> I agree to the <a hraf="terms & conditions.html></a> </input>
                        [i want this       [this is the page i want the
                         as regular             hyperlink to go to]
                            text]
```

how can i make it right? Thanks!

Comment: `<input>` element is not block element, so you can't place any other elements inside it (as it does not have closing tag `</input>`, only self closing version `<input type="checkbox"/>`. You need to create wrapper for your elements and style it to look like one input

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `label` like:

```html
<label for='checkterm'>I agree to the <a href="terms & conditions.html">terms</a></label>
<input type="checkbox" id='checkterm'>
```

Reference:

- [`<label>`: The Input Label element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

---

I recommend that you also read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) article regarding `inputs` (I see that you make mistakes)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```html
     <input style="float:none; vertical-align: middle;" type="checkbox" id="agree" />
      <label style="display:inline; float:none" for="agree">
        I agree with the <a href="terms & conditions.html"></a>terms and conditions.
      </label>
```

Also check that you put the tag correctly. `<a href=...>`, you've got a mistake (you did put hraf).

Comment: Thank you for helping me! i tried, it shows the hyperlink the way i wanted but it gives me this error: Cannot GET /pages/terms-and-conditions

Comment: Try it now with the new code. I adapted my code to your href.

Comment: Thank you so much man, it totally worked, i've been stocked on it for like an hour lol, take care!

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked! Same to you!